# mysql query of chat messages

Tags: mysql, messaging

i have a table called messages

```
id - message - sender - receiver
1  -  hello  -   1    -    2     
2  -  hello  -   1    -    2     
3  -  hello  -   2    -    1     
4  -  hello  -   3    -    1     
5  -  hello  -   1    -    3     
6  -  hello  -   23   -    1     
7  -  hello  -   1    -    23     
8  -  hello  -   1    -    2
```

and users

```
id   -   name   -       email     -   phone
1    -   abc1   -   abc@gmail.com - 1234567890
2    -   abc2   -   abc@gmail.com - 1234567890
3    -   abc3   -   abc@gmail.com - 1234567890
23   -  abc23   -   abc@gmail.com - 1234567890
```

now i want to select all the users from messages table where userid 1 has chat with (excluding userid 1) group by sender and receiver.

in other words i want to select only those records from messages table where user 1 has chat with

currently i have this sql query

```
SELECT * FROM messages INNER JOIN users ON messages.sender=users.id OR messages.receiver=users.id WHERE users.id!='1' GROUP BY users.id
```

but problem with this query is 
its selecting all the records where userid 1 is not in users table

i want to select only those records from user table where user 1 has chated with.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: This might be a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ because in my opinion this is not exactly server related.

Comment: They'e all id 1

Comment: nope.. my mistake i corrected it

Comment: not sure what you mean. you say "excluding userid 1", but then you say "problem - userid 1 is not in users table"

Comment: Change `GROUP BY users.id` to `ORDER BY users.id`. Your description isn't a grouping kind of function because there is no aggregate function over groups. It sounds like you just want them together (which is `ORDER BY`).

Comment: i tried your suggestion  danblack but no success..